# AJAX Error: TypeError: 'arguments', 'callee', and 'caller' cannot be accessed in this context

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ajax, error-handling, safari

I'm doing an API call on a system and am receiving this error. I can get a response with curl and Postman with the same URL, but safari throws this error when using Angular's $http.get() method.

This will also work in production.  The error only occurs during development.

Searching this error turns up similar, but different questions.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found out that this error is actually a X-origin issue.

If you are only experiencing this during Dev, in Safari, just disable X-origin restrictions in the Develop menu. Otherwise, from here, you can find a few solutions on handling X-origin issues. But at least now you'll know a possible cause of the error.

I hope this helps someone!

Comment: sounds like a bad choice to turn it off when a user will not have it turned off. The real solution is to set the appropriate CORS headers.

Comment: is this really the solution? Do you expect people using your site to disable X-origin restrictions before they can use it?

Comment: The question was really "what does the error mean?". Which I had to figure out on my own and hope to save others from spending an hour figuring it out themselves.  I updated the Q&A to make it more clear that for me, the error only occurred during dev, so disabling CORS was an easy fix.