# AJAX request not calling python-flask method

Tags: javascript, python, ajax, flask, web-development-server

I'm trying to call an AJAX request with XMLHttpRequest() from JavaScript to a flask server but the problem is that `request.open()` doesn't seem to work as the python function is not being called.
The .js code is

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
    document.querySelector(".messaging-channel").onclick = () => {
        const channelName = document.querySelector(".messaging-channel").innerHTML;
        var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
        request.open("POST", "/channel");

        window.alert(`${channelName}`);
        request.onload = () => {
            const response = JSON.parse(request.responseText);
            const messages = response.channel;
            window.alert(`${messages} are the messages.`);
        };
    };
});
```

and the flask method is

```
@app.route("/channel", methods=["POST", "GET"])
def channel():
    print("Working python\n\n")
    return jsonify({"channel": "Working"})
```

Both of the files are connected and `` window.alert(`${channelName}`); `` executes fine in the .js file. Though the request is not calling the python function. I also checked this on the debugger by safari and it would say that: 
*arguments: TypeError: 'arguments', 'callee', and 'caller' cannot be accessed in this context.
caller: TypeError: 'arguments', 'callee', and 'caller' cannot be accessed in this context.*

I have attached the photo of the debugger's relevant parts.
[image: Debugger]

Comment: maybe you should use `request.send()`

Comment: Isn't that for GET but I'm sending POST method

Comment: `send()` is for both `GET` and `POST` and `send(data)` is for `POST`. Without `send()` you don't send request to server.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `request.send()` to send request to server.

It doesn't matter if you use `GET`, `POST`, `PUT`, `DELETE`, `HEAD`, etc.

---

```
from flask import Flask, render_template_string, jsonify

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template_string('''
<button class="messaging-channel">SUBMIT</button>

<script>
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
    document.querySelector(".messaging-channel").onclick = () => {
        const channelName = document.querySelector(".messaging-channel").innerHTML;
        var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
        request.open("POST", "/channel");

        window.alert(`${channelName}`);
        request.onload = () => {
            const response = JSON.parse(request.responseText);
            const messages = response.channel;
            window.alert(`${messages} are the messages.`);
        };

        request.send();
    };
});
</script>''')

@app.route("/channel", methods=["POST", "GET"])
def channel():
    print("Working python\n\n")
    return jsonify({"channel": "Working"})

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

Comment: The python function is now being called but request.onload function is still having the same problem. It is still giving me *arguments: TypeError: 'arguments', 'callee', and 'caller' cannot be accessed in this context.
caller: TypeError: 'arguments', 'callee', and 'caller' cannot be accessed in this context.*

Comment: this code works for me without problem. I didn't try to run it with debuger and maybe all your problem is only debuger. OR maybe problem is more complex and need full code to see this error. OR maybe server has some restrictions and it makes problem to run code. Probably you should use Google to serch `onload TypeError: 'arguments', 'callee', and 'caller' cannot be accessed in this context.` Maybe someone already had this problem.

Comment: I found with Google [ReferenceError: deprecated caller or arguments usage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Errors/Deprecated_caller_or_arguments_usage) and it shows this problem when JavaScript uses `'use strict';`

Comment: I found with Google [AJAX Error: TypeError: 'arguments', 'callee', and 'caller' cannot be accessed in this context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47871301/ajax-error-typeerror-arguments-callee-and-caller-cannot-be-accessed-in) and it shows `X-origin restrictions` which can block it.